# Implementation of 8:1 MUX using 3:8 decoders and 2 input gates

Tags: cpu-architecture, decoder, digital-logic

How do I implement a 8:1 MUX using 3:8 decoders and 2 input gates?

I know how a 8:1 MUX works and how a 3:8 decoder works but I am not able to understand the approach to convert the decoder to mux using 2 input AND or OR gates.

Our Sir told this Question and the students gave the answer in split second.They said 8 AND gates and 7 OR gates are required for conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a 8:1 MUX does is selecting 1 signal out of the 8 inputs. The 3:8 decoder is where you should start with, because it can transform a 3-bit signal (the selector signal) to 8 separate signals which as a whole functions as one-hot.

Assume each input `IN*` is 1-bit. To implement a 8:1 MUX which:

- `SEL`=0 selects `IN0`
- ...
- `SEL`=7 selects `IN7`

use the following structure.

```
                 +-----+         +----+
IN0 ------------>| AND |-------->|    |
       +-------->+-----+         |    |
       |                         | OR |---> OUT
  ...  |           ...       ... |    |
       |         +-----+         |    |
IN7 ---|-------->| AND |-------->|    |
       |     +-->+-----+         +----+
     s0| ... |s7
      +-------+
      |3:8 DEC|
      +-------+
          ^
          |
       SEL[2:0]
```

`s0`=1 if `SEL`=0. ... `s7`=1 if `SEL`=7.

8 `AND` gates plus one-hot encoded `s*` signals permits only one `IN*` input pass at any given time. **Please note that tall `OR` gate actually represents 7 `OR` gates.** Because only 2-input gates are allowed, you need 7 `OR` gates to *OR* 8 signals together.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.I have more clarity on the approach now.